# ¿Cómo mostrar el contenido de un array en un string?

Tags: javascript, dom

me estoy iniciando en la programacion en javascript y tengo este problema

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titulo de Página</title>
</head>
<!---->
<body>
    <h1>Mi primera página web</h1>

    <div id="contenedor"></div>
    <script>
        var i;
        var nombre = [
            "antonio","Rodrigo","maria"
        ];
        for(i=0;i<nombre.length;i++){

            document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = "Nombre "+i+" "+nombre[i];
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

quiero que en el contenedor salgan todo el contenido del array y para ellos uso el getelementbyid para seleccionar el id del contenedor para que me atrape el div del html y pueda pintar los resultados a través del innerHTML pero solo me arroja el de "maría" y no se como puedo mostrar todos los elementos del array

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema está en que estas sobrescribiendo el valor cada vez que realizas una iteración del array porque estás usando el `=`, el cual asigna. Tendrías que utilizar el símbolo `+=` que concatena lo que ya tengas con lo nuevo.

```js
var i;
var nombre = [
   "antonio","Rodrigo","maria"
];

for(i=0;i<nombre.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML += "Nombre " + i + " " + nombre[i] + " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Mi primera página web</h1>
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

El `+=` sería lo mismo que hacer lo siguiente:

```
var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
contenedor.innerHTML = contenedor.innerHTML + "Nombre " + i + " " + nombre[i] + " ";
```

Comment: que tonto cierto tan simple y yo ahogándome en un vaso de agua no se me ocurrió eso gracias

Comment: @Efrainrodc Hay veces que los errores más simples son los más difíciles de detectar. Happy codding :)

Comment: de pana que si gracias @FranciscoRomero

Comment: @Efrainrodc si la respuesta te ayudo, Super acepta la respuesta. En cambio si no esta resuelta tu duda lo correcto es editar tu pregunta (Para conseguir la respuesta adecuada). Gracias por usar Stack Overflow